# Django template: filter in an other

Tags: python, django, django-templates

how can I put a filter in another .i've already create one named 'titl' in `blog_extras.py` :

```
 @register.filter(is_safe=True)
 def titl(texte):
     return  " %s " % texte.title()
```

and I load it in my template with :
`{% load blog_extras %}`

and then I do this:

`{%for categorie in Categories%}
    <a href="#"><div class="categorie">
        <center><h1 class="c">{{ {{categorie}} |titl }}</h1></center>

    </div></a>
    {% empty %}
    <h1>Le blog est en construction</h1>
    {%endfor%}`

but an error message appears:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/menu/ Could not parse the remainder: '{{categorie' from '{{categorie'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few too many braces. It should be

```
{{categorie|titl}}
```

and not `{{ {{categorie}} | titl }}`